# C# application with mysql database with date saved as string

Tags: c#, mysql, date

I have an application where I store a value with date-type "as  string"

The problem is that the results of the query aren't being shown correctly in C# when I execute the program, but when I apply the same query in mysql workbench the results are correct.

The date value is stored as a string in mysql; can we use comparison this way as shown or is it wrong?

```
string s = "select date  from guest,program where guestid=guest.id AND *date >= " + date + "* "' ";
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [using c# datetime in mysql update query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12195147/using-c-sharp-datetime-in-mysql-update-query)

Comment: Is "date" in your MySQL database a datetype or a string type?  And is your "date" variable in C# a string?  Also, setting up your query like that can lead to SQL injections (very bad).  It would be better to use a parameterized query, instead.

Comment: Providing your code that retrieves data from database and a sample string of your `date` variable would help us understanding the issue.

Comment: mjw no actually it is different because the string issue i checked and didn't find anything to help me . i don't know if storing the date in the database  could be the problem

Comment: Russ Yes they are both string. i'll look up the SQL injection but now i needto solve this ASAP . i am trying to produce  working code not an optimal code for now .

Answer (score 2):

Since your column in the database is a `date` column and the value you want to pass is a `DateTime` strucure, as a good pratice, try to use parameters in your command. Using Parameters in your command, you avoid a lot of problems, like sql injection, type definition, etc. For sample:

```
string sql = "select date  from guest,program where guestid=guest.id AND date >= @date";

using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("your connectionstring"))
{
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, con); 

    try 
    { 
        con.Open(); 
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("date", date); 

        using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                var dateField = (DateTime)reader["date"];
                // some task
            }
        }
    } 
    finally 
    { 
        con.Close(); 
    }
}
```

Read more here: http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorial/AdoDotNet/Lesson06

Comment: `con.Close();` as well as `try finally` is *redundant* in your code: `using` will do the work

Comment: it is a string not a Date . i meant the value is date- type but is stored as a string . sorry if it wasn't obvious :(